# Curious about the meaning of the term '&c' in Legendre's paper

Tags: math-history, least-squares, quadratic-residues

In Legendre's paper "*De Nouvelles Méthodes pour la Détermination des Orbites des Comètes*", the term $\&c$ is used. I'm not familiar with that terminology, but it seems to me that it represents higher order terms, mostly $O(t^2)$. Can anyone validate or correct my interpretation of that symbol?

Comment: No, it just mean : etc. ("et coetora")...

Comment: If you want to read more about this topic, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera

Comment: Thanks for the reply and clarifying the term Jean Marie, **&c**! It literally means etcetera. From reading that paper, I believe that by this time Taylor's series expansion was well known.
Side question, how does one mark this question as answered?

Comment: @Catriel re. side question: it's allowed here to answer one's own question. If you do that the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Jean Marie, coffemath, ***&c***, for answering my question. (Notice what I did there with ***&c***?)

Comment: [+1] for the parenthezed humor.